# MySql Two subrequest count call

Tags: mysql, count

Hello guys i have trouble with this code:

```
SELECT 

(SELECT count( * ) FROM _mark_as WHERE value =2) AS bad, 
(SELECT count( * ) FROM _mark_as WHERE value =1) AS good

FROM `_mark_as`
```

What it does, it count all "good" and "bad" values BUT, it call on every entry in _mark_as and it's not right. I want make single call that return one entry with:

```
# good # bad #
##############
#  2   #  2  #
##############
```

Help with it please.

PS: Group by is not the way out. Because first will be done selection (for all entries) and only then will be applied group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    Sum(CASE WHEN value = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as bad,
    Sum(CASE WHEN value = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as good
FROM _mark_as
```

Comment: Sounds good but is there are difference of time calling between count() and sum() ?

Comment: answer is correct, i can't 'accept' it next 5 minutes, just asking about your thoughts about in common. :)

Comment: unless your table is 10 million row plus (with giant row sizes)  I wouldn't worry about it